# Do you need to build opencv from source to get the headers?

Tags: c++, opencv

I noticed these lines in my cpp file did not work if I tried to use opencv binaries versus building from source:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco/charuco.hpp>
```

Is there a way to make this work without building from source? Building from source is very slow, and especially when I am using docker files this is problematic (yes, I know docker builds are usually cached, but when you have to break the cache, the opencv build adds a lot of slow down).

Comment: What does "did not work" means?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are in a distro like Ubuntu, you can just install the development package for that library with

```
$ sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

or on Redhat/EPEL

```
$ sudo yum install libopencv-devel
```

Your headers will be installed inside /usr

```sh
$ find /usr -name 'opencv.hpp'
/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/usr/include/boost/compute/interop/opencv.hpp
```

as well as the cmake modules (for find_package)

```sh
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/ -l
total 64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14222 Feb 17  2020 OpenCVConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   418 Feb 17  2020 OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15428 Feb 17  2020 OpenCVModules.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26215 Feb 17  2020 OpenCVModules-release.cmake
```

Within docker that's usually a line in Dockerfile (as root before switching to the end user)

```sh
RUN apt install -y libopencv-dev
```

Comment: So do I still use the same code to include the header files, or do I need to use the absolute path to these header files?

Comment: Usually you keep the code as is and use your build system to append the proper compiler directives, in this case ‘-I /usr/include/opencv4’.  On cmake that would be the command ‘include_directories(“/usr//include/opencv4”)’

Comment: Here is a tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html